# Python dictionary and list statement

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, load

What is the meaning of the statement in python for d1=data['behavior']['process'] where data=json.load(f1) and d1={}.
I am not able to interpret this statement

Comment: Is d1=={} before or after this statement? The statement gets the value for the key 'behavior' from the dictionary data, then gets the value associated with the key 'process' from that dictionary.

Comment: d1={} is before d1=data['behavior']['process'] ..

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a nested dict.

example:

```
data = {'behavior': {'process': sample_value}}
```

I this case, `data['behavior']['process']` would return `sample_value`.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer..Whatever you have answered might be correct.. will like to check the interpretation on json file..

Comment: A nice free and online option is http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. There you can just paste the content of your json file (maybe a piece of it), and visualize it in an organized nested view. Maybe it can help you understand your json structure.

Comment: thank you Renato for the link for json file viewer . I try it,

Comment: The jsonviewer really worked. But , I wanted the 'time' to be accessed now. I am not able to access it. I have posted one more post. Please anyone reply to that post with json file tree interpretation.